# What is the purpose of Float.addProduct in Swift?

Tags: swift, math, floating-point

What is the purpose of `Float.addProduct` in Swift? Are the operators `Float + Float` and `Float * Float` actually implemented using this as a base function, as in

```
let zero:Float = 0
func + (a:inout Float, b:Float) {
    a.addProduct(1,b)
}
func * (a:inout Float, b:Float) {
    0.addProduct(a,b)
}
```

Are `+` and `*` actually implemented using the same processor instruction that is being called with `addProduct`?

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/2295623-addproduct: Adds the product of the two given values to this value in place, computed **without intermediate rounding.**

Comment: Moreover, if you look at the documentation of `addingProduct`, which is the non-mutating version of `addProduct`, it states: _"This method is equivalent to the C `fma` function and implements the `fusedMultiplyAdd` operation defined by the [IEEE 754 specification](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/servlet/opac?punumber=4610933)."_

Comment: See also [Fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply–accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply–add) – useful to calculate dot products, matrix products etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Float.addProduct` performs an operation known as "Fused Multiply and Add", or FMA. This computes `a*b + c`. Importantly, though, it does so without rounding the result of `a*b` to a representable floating point number. As a result, FMA can result in significantly lower error than directly computing `a*b+c`, when properly used. It's the sort of thing where, when you need it, you'll know it.

No, regular addition and multiplication are generally not implemented through the operation this function performs; regular addition and multiplication are already available, and FMA can be significantly slower than regular multiplication and addition on some platforms.